# Converting Kendall's τ to r for meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis

I'm conducting a meta-analysis of the relationship between male sexual dimorphism (masculinity) and mating/reproductive success. I'm converting all effect sizes to r and I'm a bit unsure of how to go about converting Kendall's τ. Gilpin (1993) has a table for conversion from τ to r, but those values are approximations and I'd like to be a little more specific. Is Kendall's formula (r = sin (.5πτ)) the best way to do it?
Thanks!

Gilpin, A. R. (1993). Table for conversion of Kendall's Tau to Spearman's Rho within the context of measures of magnitude of effect for meta-analysis. Educational and psychological measurement, 53(1), 87-92.